# Moongoose require:true does not seem to work?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Mongoose schema.

```
var ContactSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  company: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  phone: { type: String, required: true }
},{ versionKey: false });
```

When I create a contact post, via

```
var contact = new Model(req.body);
contact.save( function( err, result ) {
  if( err ) {
    res.status(422).json( err );
  }
  else {
    res.status(200).json( result );
  }
})
```

and do not submit all fields, I get an error 422 as supposed. The `required: true` works.

However, when I update an existing contact via

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {new:true, select:    defaultProjection}, function( err, contact ){

if( err ) {
  res.status(422).json( err );
}
else {
  res.status(200).json( contact );
}
```

});

then I do not get any error if I leave, for example, `email` empty.

What did I do wrong? :-)

Answer (score 1):

you need to `use $set` on `update`

Try this:

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {'$set' : req.body}, 
    {new:true, select: defaultProjection}, function( err, contact ){

if( err ) {
  res.status(422).json( err );
}
else {
  res.status(200).json( contact );
}
```

Comment: It did not work. It accepts an empty field.

Comment: It did work if I added runValidators: true. I do not know how I can answer my own question, it may be related to that somebody marked this as a duplicate question. I have no idea.

Comment: you can give your own answer. Isnt it allowing you to give answer? And, if my answer helped you you can mark it as accepted.